# Android dialog orientation

Tags: android, dialog, orientation

I have an activity that creates a dialog with two buttons. When a button is clicked, I am using a view flipper to change the view of the dialog using animation.
When the orientation is changed, I want to use a landscape xml file to display the second view of the view flipper. How do I do that?

Comment: Let's assume you already created a landscape XML in the res/layout-land folder... what's your problem then? Isn't it working? Is it crashing? Be more specific, please.

Comment: Actually, the real issue is the fact that I want different ids in the layout and the layout-land xmls, and different behaviors. When I do findViewById with an id that exists only in one of them, after inflating them, it doesn't know that id... BTW, I do the findViewById in the constructor of the inheriting view, is that bad?

Answer (score 1):

You create two xml layouts for the view flipper. One called fliper.xml and put it in res/layout. You then create another file also called fliper.xml and put it in res/layout-land. This second one will be used when in landscape mode. See [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) for more details.

Comment: Thanks, but I know about layout-land. But the second view is created with an inflater. Will it take the layout-land xml when changing orientation without running through the inflater.inflate line?

Comment: And what if the two layouts have different items inside them with different ids, where do I set their data (listeners, texts, etc)? Today I do it in the constructor of the view... If the ids are different between the different layouts I cannot findViewById them...

Comment: If you want to handle exactly what happens when the device is rotated, checkout http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onConfigurationChanged%28android.content.res.Configuration%29